# How to save the different contents with same file name using MimeBodyPart?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-mail

I have tried the following code to save the attachments from mail.

```
MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
part.saveFile(myDirectory   + File.separator + fileName);
```

It worked for save the attachments but in case if "myDirectory" already contains the file named "file1.pdf" even mail contains same "file1.pdf" with different content it replaces the existing file.

In my case, **i need to save both files into directory`(file1.pdf,file1.pdf(1))`**

can anyone suggest me the way to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to save several files into one part? Or you're facing the issue when you're trying to save file with the same name but to some other part?

Comment: No. If saved directory already contains file1.pdf and if i other file from mail it having same name file1.pdf with different content. my code replace that already existing file1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the file already exists using the java.io.File.exists method, and if it does exist then choose a different name for the file before saving it.